# WPF Save text that is trimmed

Tags: wpf, textblock

Let's say I have this text I want to put in a TextBlock:

> Counting one two three four five six seven eight nine ten

I have a textblock that is setup with a maxwidth and maxheight, with wrap. If the text could not fix in the textblock, it will get cut-off. The requirement is to display whatever text can fit (including wrap) but determine which text gets cut off and save it in a variable so I can process the text later on, perhaps on a different Textblock later on.

So if

> Counting one two three four

is the only part that fits, I need to save

> five six seven eight nine ten

on a variable

Sample:

```
 ----------------
| Counting one   |
| two three four |
 ----------------
```

I need to then save

> five six seven eight nine ten

Comment: looks like a really odd requirement. Why don't you simply `TextWrapping="Wrap"`?

Comment: TextWrapping="Wrap" is already there. Since there is maxheight and maxwidth, the text could be cut-off. Updated question...

Comment: This would probably be a lot easier if you use a fixed-width font

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`FormattedText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.formattedtext(v=vs.110).aspx) to get the width of a TextBlock:

```
string text = "Counting one two three four five six seven eight nine ten";
var formattedText = new FormattedText(
    text,
    CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture,
    FlowDirection.LeftToRight,
    new Typeface(theTextBlock.FontFamily, theTextBlock.FontStyle, theTextBlock.FontWeight, theTextBlock.FontStretch),
    theTextBlock.FontSize,
    Brushes.Black);
```

So basically, it's a matter of iterating over the words and computing the length of each, until you've exceeded the max length... (untested, but hopefully not too far off) ...

```
Func<string, double> GetWidthFunc(TextBlock textBlock)
{
    return text => {
        var formattedText = new FormattedText(
        text,
        CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture,
        FlowDirection.LeftToRight,
        new Typeface(theTextBlock.FontFamily, theTextBlock.FontStyle, theTextBlock.FontWeight, theTextBlock.FontStretch),
        theTextBlock.FontSize,
        Brushes.Black);
        return formattedText.Width;
    };
}

string GetRemainingText(TextBlock textBlock)
{
    Func<string, double> getWidth = GetWidthFunc(textBlock);
    double maxWidth = textBlock.MaxWidth;
    string[] words = textBlock.Text.Split(' ');
    double totalLength = 0;
    for (int i = 0 ; i < words.Length ; i++)
        if ( (totalLength += getWidth(words[i] + (i > 0 ? " " : "") ) ) > maxWidth )
            return string.Join(" ", words.Skip(i));
    return "";
}
```

Comment: Your answer, however, does not account for TextWrap